# JPanel - drawing a black transparent png with 50% opacity

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paint

Let me ask my question with a photo :)

[image]

The left-hand side picture is the transparent photo in Adobe Photoshop, and the right-hand side is the result in my java program.
I've used the "drawImage" method, in body of a overridden "paint(Graphics g)" method.
How can I make it look transparent?
looks like only 0 or 100 transparency is acceptable here...

Comment: Is the image a JPG (bad) or a PNG (good)? Please show relevant code.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter it is transparent around the black part, I also noticed it in the title so it is definitely a png picture !!!

Comment: Look up `AlphaComposite` - [Compositing Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/compositing.html)

Comment: [And for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15996314/alphacomposite-transparency-with-repaint-overlaps-into-black/15996385#15996385)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this is what you are looking for:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class TransparentImage extends JPanel
{
    private BufferedImage backImage, frontImage;
    private float alpha = 1;

    public TransparentImage()
    {
        try
        {
//          backImage = ImageIO.read(new File("mong.jpg") );
            backImage = ImageIO.read(new File("grass.jpg") );
            frontImage = ImageIO.read(new File("dukeWaveRed.gif") );
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return new Dimension(backImage.getWidth(), backImage.getHeight());
    }

    public void setAlpha(float alpha)
    {
        this.alpha = alpha;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        //  Paint background image

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        int x = (getWidth() - backImage.getWidth())/2;
        int y = (getHeight()- backImage.getHeight())/2;
        g2.drawRenderedImage(backImage, AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y));

        //  Paint foreground image with appropriate alpha value

        Composite old = g2.getComposite();
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, alpha));
        x = (getWidth() - frontImage.getWidth())/2;
        y = (getHeight()- frontImage.getHeight())/2;
        g2.drawRenderedImage(frontImage, AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y));
        g2.setComposite(old);
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        final TransparentImage app = new TransparentImage();

        JSlider slider = new JSlider();
        slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener()
        {
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
            {
                JSlider source = (JSlider) e.getSource();
                app.setAlpha(source.getValue()/100f);
            }
        });
        slider.setValue(100);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Transparent Image");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( app );
        frame.add(slider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Provide a background and foreground image. Use the slider to adjust the alpha value of the foreground image.